# How to find old recovery files on Abinitio production boxes?

Tags: ab-initio

Can any one throw some light on the process of finding old recovery files in abinitio production boxes

Comment: Got my answer thanks every one.
Should go into temp directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ab Initio's Co>Op creates recovery files in the working directory as *jobname***.rec**

So if you have an idea where the graphs/psets were executed from, you could simply do a find:

```
find . -name \*.rec
```

Or if you have access to the AbIntio log files from the old executed jobs, you could grep them for this:

```
ABINITIO: Job may be closed and recovery file deleted by: m_rollback -d <working directory path>/<jobname>.rec
```

which shows the name of the recovery file it created.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command to find .rec files older than 60 days in current and its nested directories.

`find . -name \*.rec -mtime +60`